# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: FileVersionStatusByMeterid

Tags: java

I am getting exception `java.lang.Exception: Named query not known: FileVersionStatusByMeterid; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: FileVersionStatusByMeterid`

My config file is:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="poolDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>                
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and my properties class has defenetions for named queries

```
 public static final String FileVersionStatusByMeterid_Name = "FileVersionStatusByMeterid";
public static final String FileVersionStatusByMeterid_Query = "from ACSRateFileVersionStatus where MeterID =:meterID and FileType= :fileType";
```

and my bean class is

```
import com.duncansolutions.databus.external.constant.NamedQueryStatements;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACS_Rate_File_Version_Status")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = NamedQueryStatements.FileVersionStatusByMeterid_Name,  query  =NamedQueryStatements.FileVersionStatusByMeterid_Query)})
public class ACSRateFileVersionStatus implements java.io.Serializable {
```

Can any one tell me where am I going wrong here to avoid the exception?